# How to splice multiple values from array of objects which matches given nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to remove the array of objects if the given array of objects matches with the index but it is only removing the last index value.

How we can remove multiple values?

```js
let idArr = [[{ index: 2 }], [{ index: 3 }]];

let obj = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'abc',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'abc',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'abc',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'abc',
  },
];
let data = obj.filter((item, i) =>
  idArr.reduce((val) => val.find(({ index }) => i === index))
);

//expected output

[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'abc',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'abc',
  },
];
```

Comment: Try replacing idArr.reduce with idArr.some.

Comment: Why is `idArr` an array of arrays containing only one object each? Wouldn't it be easier for it to just be an array of objects, or even just an array containing the elements `2` and `3`?

Comment: So in the example, you are trying to remove the last two elements?

Comment: If you want to keep first two records then you might want to use: idArr.every((val) => val.find(({ index }) => i !== index))

Answer (score 0):

I think that following code achieves what you're expecting

```js
let data = obj.filter((obj, idx) => !idArr.find(id => id[0].index === idx));
```